# flask-cors not sending preflight CORS request

Tags: python, flask, server, cors, flask-cors

I want to allow only localhost as access-control-allow-origin in my Flask app. I tried searching for this issue at other places with no solution. My code is very simple and straightforward as follows :

```
from flask import Flask
from routes.routes import *
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}})

app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, prefix='/drax')

app.add_url_rule('/template/<actionId>/<actionName>', None, templateActions, methods=['GET'])
```

The above should ONLY allow any request from localhost:3000 and not from anywhere else, like localhost:8080. But even when I make the request from port 8080 (another web app), it allows the request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify a valid http origin in your request as under:

```
CORS(
        app,
        supports_credentials=True,
        resources={
            r"/*": {
                "origins": [
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    ""http://localhost"
                    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
                    "http://127.0.0.1,

                ]
            }
        },
    )
```

I do not think http://local is a valid origin

Comment: I edited and changed the question. My point is, no OPTIONS request is being sent.